# Android: How handle message error from the server using Volley?

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using **Volley** for my Android app to fetch data from my server. It works well except when handling the error from my server. My server sends this response when there is a mistake:

```
{
    "status": 400,
    "message": "Errors (2): A name is required- Julien is already used. Not creating."
}
```

My goal is to get the message and then display it in a `Toast`. I followed some sample for how to do this, but it doesn't work.

**There is my error listener :**

```
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            int  statusCode = error.networkResponse.statusCode;
            NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;

            Log.d("testerror",""+statusCode+" "+response.data);
            // Handle your error types accordingly.For Timeout & No connection error, you can show 'retry' button.
            // For AuthFailure, you can re login with user credentials.
            // For ClientError, 400 & 401, Errors happening on client side when sending api request.
            // In this case you can check how client is forming the api and debug accordingly.
            // For ServerError 5xx, you can do retry or handle accordingly.
            if( error instanceof NetworkError) {
            } else if( error instanceof ClientError) {
            } else if( error instanceof ServerError) {
            } else if( error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
            } else if( error instanceof ParseError) {
            } else if( error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
            } else if( error instanceof TimeoutError) {
            }
            showProgress(false);
            mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
            mPasswordView.requestFocus();

        }
```

**And there the result of my debugger :** testerror﹕ 400 [B@430b8d60

**EDIT:** Moreover my error.getMessage() is null.

So I don't understand why my variable response.data is not the response from my server.

If someone know how I can get the message from my server it's will be cool.

Thx,

Answer (score 156, accepted):

I've implemented something  similar to this, and it's relatively simple.  Your log message is printing out what looks like gibberish, because `response.data` is really a byte array - not a `String`.  Also, a `VolleyError` is really just an extended `Exception`, so [Exception](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Exception.html).getMessage() likely wouldn't return what you are looking for unless you override the parsing methods for parsing your `VolleyError` in your extended `Request` class.  A really basic way to handle this would be to do something like:

```
//In your extended request class
@Override
protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError){
        if(volleyError.networkResponse != null && volleyError.networkResponse.data != null){
                VolleyError error = new VolleyError(new String(volleyError.networkResponse.data));
                volleyError = error;
            }

        return volleyError;
    }
}
```

If you add this to your extended `Request` classes, your `getMessage()` should at least not return null. I normally don't really bother with this, though, since it's easy enough to do it all from within your `onErrorResponse(VolleyError e)` method.

You should use a JSON library to simplify things -- I use [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for example or you could use Apache's `JSONObject`s which shouldn't require an additional external library.  The first step is to get the response JSON sent from your server as a `String` (in a similar fashion to what I just demonstrated), next you can optionally convert it to a [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) (using either apache's `JSONObject`s and `JsonArray`s, or another library of your choice) or just parse the `String` yourself.  After that, you just have to display the `Toast`.

Here's some example code to get you started:

```
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
     String json = null;

     NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
     if(response != null && response.data != null){
         switch(response.statusCode){
             case 400:
                  json = new String(response.data);
                  json = trimMessage(json, "message");
                  if(json != null) displayMessage(json);
                  break;
             }
            //Additional cases
     }
}

public String trimMessage(String json, String key){
    String trimmedString = null;

    try{
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
        trimmedString = obj.getString(key);
    } catch(JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    return trimmedString;
}

//Somewhere that has access to a context
public void displayMessage(String toastString){
    Toast.makeText(context, toastString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: You are exactly write :) I found the answer just before your post. And I also create a class MessageServer with 2 attributs : status and message like this I use gson to convert my string into this class and then get the message.

Comment: Hi, I just want to add that the @Override approach you provided (which I think is very elegant) isn't flexible if you want to check for networkresponse data, since you discard that information and create a new VolleyError with a String message in it. Unfortunately it's not possible to create an instance with both the original networkResponse and a custom message.

Comment: It isn't impossible, it just requires a subclassed VolleyError implementation, and in many cases checking the subclassed type of your VolleyError is necessary in onErrorResponse(VolleyError e) anyways.

Comment: if I use `json = new String(response.data);` I get error "Unterminated array at character x" (where x is index in byte[] data).   This error is resolved by passing UTF-8  `json = new String(response.data, "UTF-8"); // this works well`

Comment: This works, but I think it's very important to note that when you create a new `VolleyError` with a message, you lose other attributes of the original error such as `networkResponse`. If you don't want any of the complex error handling in your second example, you either have to be okay with this loss or create a subclass of `VolleyError` and override its `getMessage()` method.

Comment: @yuval, you can add check if the `getMessage()` is null and apply this error handling, otherwise display the `getMessage()` error. I found it useful

Answer (score 6):

try this class to handle all erros

```
public class VolleyErrorHelper {
        /**
         * Returns appropriate message which is to be displayed to the user
         * against the specified error object.
         *
         * @param error
         * @param context
         * @return
         */

        public static String getMessage (Object error , Context context){
            if(error instanceof TimeoutError){
                return context.getResources().getString(R.string.timeout);
            }else if (isServerProblem(error)){
                return handleServerError(error ,context);

            }else if(isNetworkProblem(error)){
                return context.getResources().getString(R.string.nointernet);
            }
            return context.getResources().getString(R.string.generic_error);

        }

        private static String handleServerError(Object error, Context context) {

            VolleyError er = (VolleyError)error;
            NetworkResponse response = er.networkResponse;
            if(response != null){
                switch (response.statusCode){

                    case 404:
                    case 422:
                    case 401:
                        try {
                            // server might return error like this { "error": "Some error occured" }
                            // Use "Gson" to parse the result
                            HashMap<String, String> result = new Gson().fromJson(new String(response.data),
                                    new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {
                                    }.getType());

                            if (result != null && result.containsKey("error")) {
                                return result.get("error");
                            }

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        // invalid request
                        return ((VolleyError) error).getMessage();

                    default:
                        return context.getResources().getString(R.string.timeout);
                }
            }

            return context.getResources().getString(R.string.generic_error);
        }

        private static boolean isServerProblem(Object error) {
            return (error instanceof ServerError || error instanceof AuthFailureError);
        }

        private static boolean isNetworkProblem (Object error){
            return (error instanceof NetworkError || error instanceof NoConnectionError);
        }
```

Comment: This answer has a better error handling for `Volley`

Comment: Just a small suggestion: NoConnectionError is a subclass of NetworkError, so your OR operation will be redundant in isNetworkProblem() method. You might as well just check for NetworkError.