# Volley onResponseError = null

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I recently lost my work due to hardware failure. I have cloned the Android project from GitHub and rewrote the PHP scripts and rewrote the database but the registration function I have written is no longer working, despite working before the failure.

I have located the error in the logcat but cannot work out what is happening. It is in this area of the code:

```
 @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Register Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
```

and the logcat reads:

04-21 12:57:42.476 26530-26530/com.example.xxx.xxxxxE/RegisterActivity: Login Error: null

When I follow the url in the logcat it is the response that required parameters are missing from the PHP script.

```
{"error":true,"error_msg":"Required parameters (first name, last name, handicap, email or password) is missing!"}
```

so it is reaching the PHP.

The rest of the code is here:

Android Register Activity:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {

//Variable declarations
private static final String TAG = RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private Button btnReg;
private Button btnLinkToLogin;
private EditText inputFirstName;
private EditText inputLastName;
private EditText inputEmail;
private EditText inputPassword;
private EditText inputConfirmPassword;
private EditText inputHandicap;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private SessionManager session;
private SQLiteHandler db;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    inputFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstName);
    inputLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastName);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    inputConfirmPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.confirmPassword);
    inputHandicap = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.handicap);
    btnReg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReg);
    btnLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLogin);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);

    session= new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

    if(session.isLoggedIn()){
        Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,
                MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    btnReg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String firstName = inputFirstName.getText().toString().trim();
            String lastName = inputLastName.getText().toString().trim();
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();
            String handicap = inputHandicap.getText().toString().trim();

            if(inputPassword.getText().toString().equals(inputConfirmPassword.getText().toString())){
                if(!firstName.isEmpty() && !lastName.isEmpty() && !email.isEmpty() &&
                        !password.isEmpty() && !handicap.isEmpty()){
                    registerUser(firstName, lastName, email, password, handicap);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please check you have entered the correct details", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Passwords do not match!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });

    btnLinkToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });
}

private void registerUser(final String firstName, final String lastName, final String email, final String password, final String handicap) {
    String tag_string_req = "req_register";

    pDialog.setMessage("Registering...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                if (!error) {
                    String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                    JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                    String firstName = user.getString("firstName");
                    String lastName = user.getString("lastName");
                    String email = user.getString("email");
                    int handicap = user.getInt("handicap");

                    db.addUser(firstName, lastName, uid, email, handicap);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account successfully created. You may now log in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            RegisterActivity.this,
                            LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {

                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    },new Response.ErrorListener(){

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Register Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams(){
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("firstName", firstName);
            params.put("lastName", lastName);
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);
            params.put("handicap", handicap);

            return params;
        }
    };


    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }


private void showDialog() {
    if(!pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.show();
}

private void hideDialog() {
    if(pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
}

}
```

PHP Script

```
<?php
  require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';

 $db = new DB_Functions();

$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if(isset($_POST['firstName']) && isset($_POST['lastName']) && 
isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['handicap']) && 
isset($_POST['password'])){

$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$handicap = $_POST['handicap'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if($db->userExists($email)){
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Email taken";
    echo json_encode($response);
}else{
    $user = $db->storeUser($firstName, $lastName, $email, $handicap, $password);
    if($user){

        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
        $response["user"]["firstName"] = $user["first_name"];
        $response["user"]["lastName"] = $user["last_name"];
        $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
        $response["user"]["handicap"] = $user["handicap"];
        echo json_encode($response);
    }else{
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
}else{
$response["error"] = TRUE;
$response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters (first name, last name, handicap, email or password) is missing!";
echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

Comment: Also of note when testing in Advanced Rest Client, it works fine and the response is received correctly.

Comment: Check first [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24700973/6140684)

Comment: this code is from androidhive. just follow the post and comments on that post you will get your answer

Comment: this error occure network latency when your server takes too long time to response

Comment: Answer was found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366976/wamp-error-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-phpmyadmin-on-this-s