# Volley equivalent of HttpURLConnection's getResponseMessage() method?

Tags: android, android-volley

`[HTTP/1.1 500 xxxx 1223ms]`

That is the HTTP response I receive in Firefox's console, when I try to open a url on my PC.

Could anyone please explain how to get the "xxxx" reponse text using Volley on Android?

I have tried some things without any luck.

`volleyError.networkResponse.statusCode` return the int 500. But I couldn't find any way to retrieve the xxxx string after that.

`volleyError.networkResponce.data` is not null but returns an empty string (also checked the size of the byte array and it was 0).

`HttpURLConnection` has a method called `getResponseMessage()` which returns the required text. How to do it with Volley?

Comment: Error 500 is always Internal Server Error, so I guess here xxxx will always be the same. So in android u can check the code volley returns and if it is 500 display internal server error.

Comment: @GauravJindal no, I specifically asked this question because xxxx is not the same in my case.

Comment: Are u sure the error code is 500 and u get different xxxx? Because till date whatever I have studied I have always seen error 500 being Internal Server Error! If what u say is true then I would love to know few examples what error is there I.e. what r u getting instead of this xxxx (Just for my knowledge)

Comment: @GauravJindal error responses [can be customised](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html)

Comment: @jankigadhiya thanks for your reply but I'm not sure what my volley implementation has to do with what I have asked in the question. I simply need the HTTP response text. I already have the response code in the overridden onErrorResponse method of the Response.ErrorListener.

Comment: @jankigadhiya please read the question properly. I have mentioned that `[HTTP/1.1 500 xxxx 1223ms]` is the response I received in Firefox's console on my **PC**. On Android, it is possible to get the response code (500) using `volleyError.networkResponse.statusCode` but I couldn't find a way to retrieve the response text (xxxx). So what I need is a way to get the text which appears after the code in an HTTP response.

Comment: Great to know that our responses can also be customized.

Comment: Have you read [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37619279/cannot-retrieve-error-message-from-server-in-error-listener-of-volley-in-android/37627087#37627087)?

Comment: @BNK no I hadn't. But I don't think it will work because in my case the byte array returned by `volleyError.networkResponce.data` does not have any bytes. It will just return an empty string no matter what charset is used. Also, e.getMessage() returned null. So, the catch block won't work either. `HttpURLConnection` has a method called `getResponseMessage()` which works perfectly. Not sure why Volley is missing such a basic thing.

Comment: If your web service published in Internet, pls share it to check more. Moreover, you can use some tool such as Postman then post the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Did you try volleyError.getMessage() ??

Comment: Yes I did. It returned null.

Answer (score 0):

The VolleyError gives object of NetworkResponse which will give you the response data or header or error code returned from server.

So in this case to get the error you can do this:

```
String response  = new String(volleyError.networkResponse.data);
```

The string response will contain whatever your server returns.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I am not downvoting this but you didn't read my question properly. As I have already mentioned, `volleyError.networkResponce.data` which is a byte array returns 0 when the size is queried and hence an empty string. So, your answer is invalid. I know for sure that the url does return a reponse text along with the code because Firefox can display it. But `volleyError.networkResponce.data` is not the way to retrieve it using volley unless the reponse is explicitly returned as data by the server.

Comment: Ohh I am sorry, I didn't read the question again after I got this working.

Comment: BTW networkResponse will show the text same as what you get when u try from browser. U have written the output is from console but is it the same thing which is shown on page? For example this is a wrong link: http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/29366011/reviews?&api_key=87959acdd79d2f46bb2ea5cea9b1f  ... when I checked the string response I got the same thing.

Comment: What you see on the webpage is just an optional message sent by the server. It might or might not be the same as HTTP response. For instance, when I opened the moviedb link provided by you, console shows the following output `[HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 1198ms]`

Comment: Also, in a lot of cases, if there is an error, only a blank white page is shown. But the console will still show you the HTTP response.

Comment: Yes that's is what I wanted to say, the console might be a packet sniffer like wiresshark while networkResponse gives response by opening input stream with your URL. I read this question because of the android tag but this question is more of a back end thing. You should configure ur backend to write some output on the page so that Volley/networkResponse object can read it.

Comment: The server is not under my control. And I disagree that this is a back end related issue. An app might need access to the whole HTTP response, particulary considering that they can be customised. Also, networkResponse easily returns the statusCode from the same HTTP response. So, I don't think providing the text which comes along with it should be too much to ask. But anyway, thanks for your time!