# onResponse method doesnt work

Tags: android, spring-mvc, android-volley

I have a strange problem that my onResponse method in Volley is not called. Everything in the controller is ok, data is saved to the database but onResponse I got nothing. I always get the "connection problem" instead...

```
JSONObject newUser = new JSONObject();
        try {
            newUser.put("login", login.toString());
            newUser.put("password", password.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("USER TO SAVE: " + newUser.toString());
        JsonObjectRequest urlAccStringRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, urlAcc, newUser, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                System.out.println("Good morning " + login.toString());
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(RegisterIndividualActivity.this, "Connection error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //this is what i got
            }
        });
```

And this is the controller (I mean, this is just a method of the big controller class), which works properly, data is saved, and everything is printed on the screen:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void register(
            @RequestParam("login") String login,
            @RequestParam("password") String password,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model
    ){
        System.out.println("\nIn REGISTER controller...");
        UserModel uM = new UserModel();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        uM.setAccountType("Client");


        try {
            System.out.println("\nTrying to save...");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
            String json = "";
            String line;
            while((line=reader.readLine())!=null) json += line;
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            System.out.println(jsonObject);
            uM.setLogin(jsonObject.getString("login"));
            uM.setPassword(jsonObject.getString("password"));
            userDAO.save(uM);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**@EDIT** Added what I found (thanks to comments)

```
W/System.err: com.b.a.k: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
W/System.err:     at com.b.a.a.i.a(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at com.b.a.g.run(Unknown Source)
W/System.err: Caused by: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:156)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
W/System.err:   ... 2 more
```

Comment: Attach your stracktrace error please

Comment: There are no errors, the method is just not called

Comment: if onResponse is not called, that means that onErrorResponse is called, so get the error string from `VolleyError error`

Comment: @MatPag sorry, I don't understand. Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: @MatPag do you mean error.printStackTrace() ?

Comment: Yes, try with printStackTrace() and see if it prints something on the logcat console

Comment: logcat console is empty

Comment: i mean, i can't see errors there

Comment: Copy [this class here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33692530/2910520) and then inside `onErrorResponse` call `Log.e("VOLLEY_ERROR", VolleyErrorHelper.getMessage(error, context))`. In this class you can omit some not defined strings because they are not fundamental. You can remove the Gson part too

Comment: @MatPag what should figure as "context" variable?

Comment: @MatPag sorry, I don't know how to make use of that class

Comment: Every context should work. Like Activity or Application Context

Comment: If you are not able to implement that class we cant do anything... Good luck

Comment: I implemented that class, I just dont know which context put there...

Comment: @MatPag updated question

Comment: The error you are receiving means that there is no json response inside the body. That's why the Json parser crash. In this case there are 2 possible causes: 1) You are sending a wrong request 2) The server is not responding correctly